# what are the steps to using ruby gem guard-shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, shopify, guard

I am currently creating a theme on Shopify and found a ruby gem called guard-shopify. I am struggling to use the gem. It is installed and i got to the point of adding the api key and secret password but now I am struggling to find out how to go about editing theme files locally and getting it to work with guard shopify so it pushes the most recent changes to the shopify account via guard.

Does anyone have good experience using this ruby gem?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

try the shopify_theme gem - it has a watch option - https://rubygems.org/gems/shopify_theme